# primefaces autocomplete, how to convert a list of objects from a database query

Tags: jsf, autocomplete, primefaces, converters, pojo

I have my autocomplete component connecting to my managed bean which then connects to my service layer and gets list from the database. I am trying to reference the showcase and any other thing I find online, but I can not get my autocomplete to work. I had a cast exception, so it looked like I needed a converter. But I am having trouble writing the converter. I'm confused on how everything is passed along.

```
        <p:autoComplete id="placesSearchBar" value="#{searchBarBean.place}" completeMethod="#{searchBarBean.findSimilarPlaces}"
                        var="Place" itemLabel="#{Place.name}" itemValue="#{Place}" converter="PlaceConverter" />

        public class SearchBarBean 
    {
        private Place place;
        private SearchQueryService searchQueryService;
        private Criteria criteria;

        /**
         * @return the place
         */
        public Place getPlace() {
            return place;
        }

        /**
         * @param place the place to set
         */
        public void setPlace(Place place) {
            this.place = place;
        }

        /**
         * @return the searchQueryService
         */
        public SearchQueryService getSearchQueryService() {
            return searchQueryService;
        }

        /**
         * @param searchQueryService the searchQueryService to set
         */
        public void setSearchQueryService(SearchQueryService searchQueryService) {
            this.searchQueryService = searchQueryService;
        }

        /**
         * @return the criteria
         */
        public Criteria getCriteria() {
            return criteria;
        }

        /**
         * @param criteria the criteria to set
         */
        public void setCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
            this.criteria = criteria;
        }

        public List<Place> findSimilarPlaces(String query)
        {
            getCriteria().setName(query);
            List<Place> places = getSearchQueryService().findPlaces(criteria);
            return places;
        }
    }

    public class PlaceConverter implements Converter
{
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String submittedValue) {
        SearchBarBean searchBarBean = new SearchBarBean();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object value) {
         return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You converter must do two things: convert a string (which gets submitted by your page) into an instance of your pojo and convert an instance of you pojo into a string so that it can be displayed on your page.

You could achieve that by returning the primary key for place in your getAsString method. Then, in your getAsObject method, you would get that string containing the primary key for the selected item and query the database for the associated record. For that to work you'd have to have access to your query service from the converter. Give that a shot and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your suggestion. Is this a normal strategy to hit the db in the converter? Also, I understand what you are telling me to do, but I am very new to jsf/primefaces, and I do not understand the converter relationship to the managed bean and page to actually write the code. I'm sorry, but would you mind helping me more with this code?

Comment: I must confess I didn't like the idea of hitting the database that often either. But it's a pretty quick primary key lookup. It's even less of an issue if you're using cache. Also, springfuse, which is a popular code gen tool for jsf projects, uses that technique; check this out: https://github.com/jaxio/generated-projects/blob/master/jsf2-primefaces-spring/src/main/generated-java/com/jaxio/web/converter/GenericJsfConverter.java

Comment: Ps: look into using springfuse for your project. Ps 2: I've got nothing to do with springfuse

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yeah I suppose you're right, especially when it is indexed. I'm going to look at the link you sent me. I think it will me understand these converters better if I understood what var, itemLabel, and itemValue are corresponding to. That code, I just copied from the showcase example (which seems to not be working on their site either :0 )

Comment: Var is the name of the variable you refer to on the itemLabel and itemValue fields. If you had var="item", you'd have something like itemValue="#{item}". Item label is what actually gets displayed on the page. And itemValue is what actually gets passed to the converter. If this was helpful remember to vote. Cheers

Comment: That definitely  helps, thank you very much. I just was getting confused on the whole concept of what is getting passed into the converter, if the completeMethod is being executed first, and what is being displayed (if it something passed back to the managed bean, etc.). But if I understand it correctly...the completeMethod runs first (get a list of objects), returns it to itemValue. Then the converter takes each itemValue (iterates through list) and converts it to string one at a time, then that string gets passed to the asObject method, in which you can convert the string back to an object.